# Javascript:: textContent/innerText of firstChild

Tags: javascript, html, console, innertext

My code is pretty much explain itself of what I'm about to get :

```
<div id=player>
    <div class="button hand">&#9658;</div>
    <div class=time>00:00/02:25</div>   
    <div class="timeline hand"><span class="now hand"></span></div>
</div>

<script>

var myPlayer=document.getElementById('player').firstChild;
var playerStatus=(myPlayer.innerText||myPlayer.textContent);

console.log(playerStatus);

</script>
```

I'm expect to get the ascii value `&#9658;` on console.

Small tweak needed here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both `id` and `class` available, so use `querySelector()`.

```
var myPlayer=document.querySelector('#player > .button.hand');
```

This also has the benefit of working in IE8.

---

Also, a shortcut for `innerText/textContent` is to check for it at the top of your script, and store the appropriate key in a string.

```
var text = ("textContent" in document) ? "textContent" : "innerText";
```

Then use square brackets with the `text` variable.

```
var myPlayer=document.querySelector('#player > .button.hand');
var playerStatus=(myPlayer[text]);
```

Then you can actually shorten it like this:

```
var playerStatus=document.querySelector('#player > .button.hand')[text];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var myPlayer=document.getElementById('player').firstElementChild;
```

The problem is that the first child of `#player` is a text node itself. What you're looking for is the first *element* child of `#player`.

A minor note: `firstElementChild` isn't supported by IE8-.